# Output of !cat not displayed in jupiter notebook

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to view a text file and the following command is not displaying the contents of the text file in my jupyter notebook:

```
    !cat textfile.txt
```

Comment: `!cat /path/to/textfile.txt`?

Comment: My textfile is in the same folder as the notebook. It didnt work for the first few runs. Now it is working

Answer (score -1):

You must try next: !cat {textfile.txt}